# Ajax requests from loop accessing variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have to create a page which requests data from a camera, and then uses that information. My main issue is that in the error and success functions I have no access to the outside information regarding the index.

My current code is like this:

```
function getCameraParameter(paramList, x_callback) {
    var paramResults = {};
    var errorResults = {};
    var index = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < paramList.length; index++)
    {
        (function(innerIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/params.cgi?getParameter&" + paramList[innerIndex],
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                timeout: 30000,
                success: function(x_data) {
                    var value;
                    var el = paramList[innerIndex];

                    value = new RegExp(el + '=([^\n]+)').exec(x_data) || [];
                    if (value.length > 1)
                        paramResults[el] = value[1];

                    if (paramResults.length + errorResults.length === paramList.length)
                    {
                        x_callback(paramResults, errorResults.length > 0);
                    }
                },
                error: function(e) {                
                    errorResults[paramList[innerIndex]] = "";
                    if (paramResults.length + errorResults.length === paramList.length)
                    {
                        x_callback(paramResults, true);
                    }
                }
            });
        })(index);
    }
}

function cameraTest()
{
    getCameraParameter(["Resolution", "CameraIP", "CameraSerialNumber"], printParameters);
}

function printParameters(paramValues, is_error)
{
    if (is_error)
        console.log("Error occurred\n");

    for (var key in paramValues)
    {
        if (paramValues.hasOwnProperty(key))
            console.log(key + "->" + paramValues[key] + "\n");
    }
}
```

In the Ajax requests, the innerIndex is `undefined`, and I found no work-around to that so far. Also the `paramResults` and `errorResults` are unknown, which are a pain, and I don't really want to make them global objects. How do I fix this?

Edit: note that I get the valid results, like CameraResolution=1920x1080, so that part works, but I need access to the index of the loop of the Ajax call somehow.

Comment: get rid of the `()` around your anonymous function inside the for loop and `errorResults` etc should be accessible again

Comment: I can't see any way that `innerIndex` could be undefined. Are you sure that is the behaviour you are experiencing? It isn't something else that is undefined? Try providing a [mcve]. Add example input data. Remove extraneous stuff (e.g. all the processing you do inside success or all the ajax call entirely) from inside the loop.

Comment: @messerbill — How does that work? I would expect that removing the `()` would mean the JS parser would see the `function` keyword in statement context, then throw an error when the next token was the argument list instead of the name.

Comment: I would happily provide an example, question is, how can I emulate this behaviour offline? I need something (in this case the camera) to respond with the data.

Comment: @SinisterMJ — If the problem is that `innerIndex` is `undefined` then you don't need to use `$.ajax` at all, so nothing needs to respond to it.

Comment: @Quentin yes i guess you are right, sorry. So extract the function into an external function and call it in place

Comment: "Also the paramResults and errorResults are unknown" — Are they? Or is it just their `length` properties that don't exist?

Comment: That I don't understand. From what I am guessing (C++ developer here) is that the success callback is basically an instantiated pointer, while everything else in the function is out of scope. paramResults and errorResults show up as undefined. When I debug, in the url line, while Ajax is still constructed, they are known just fine, later on, not anymore. paramList though is always known.

Comment: I also tried in the for loop to do something like for() var sucCal = function()... ; sucCal.index = index; , but then inside that sucCal function, I was NOT able to access it. I tried with this.index, and .index, it wasn't known.

Comment: Oh, maybe clarify, innerIndex is known in the url statement, but not in the success / error return.

Comment: Objects like paramResults and errorResults do not have a .length property (unless you assign one).  You could use something like `Object.keys(paramResults).length`.

Comment: Okay, but my bigger problem really is that index variable that I somehow need. Originally paramResults and errorResults were supposed to be arrays, and I have not changed the code accordingly yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerIndex` is available in the success/error callbacks, cause every variable in JavaScript is visible in every inner scope.

The problem with your code is that you are trying to access the length of `{}` and objects don't have length.

I refactored your code to use the complete callback, which is called always whether the request was successful or not.

```
function getCameraParameter(paramList, x_callback) {
    var paramResults = {};
    var errorResults = {};
    var index = 0;
    var completed = 0;

    for (index = 0; index < paramList.length; index++)
    {
        (function(innerIndex) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/params.cgi?getParameter&" + paramList[innerIndex],
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'text',
                cache: false,
                async: true,
                timeout: 30000,
                success: function(x_data) {
                    var value;
                    var el = paramList[innerIndex];

                    value = new RegExp(el + '=([^\n]+)').exec(x_data) || [];
                    if (value.length > 1)
                        paramResults[el] = value[1];
                },
                error: function(e) { 
                    errorResults[paramList[innerIndex]] = e;
                },
                complete: function () {
                    completed++;
                    if (completed === paramList.length) {
                        x_callback(errorResults, paramResults);
                    }
                }
            });
        })(index);
    }
}

function cameraTest()
{
    getCameraParameter(["Resolution", "CameraIP", "CameraSerialNumber"], printParameters);
}

function printParameters(errorResults, paramValues)
{
    if (Object.keys(errorResults).length > 0) {
        console.log("Error occurred\n", errorResults);
    }

    for (var key in paramValues)
    {
        if (paramValues.hasOwnProperty(key))
            console.log(key + "->" + paramValues[key] + "\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Really strange why the debugger would tell me "Undefined" on innerIndex though, here it worked.